# JLabel does not change its icon property before the Thread.sleep()/this.wait()

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jlabel, event-dispatch-thread

Problem Introduction:
I'm working on a JFrame related Aplication. On some point I have to:

1. **Change Icon** of the label
2. **Stop** the Process
3. **Wait**
4. **Resume** the Process

Problem appears in the very beginning. If I pause my aplication - JLabel icon won't change.
Currently I tried several pause methods, those including: **Thread.sleep()**, **this.wait()** and variations with **synchronize**. I also tried to put **.updateUI()** in every appropriate and NOT place. The problem itself makes no sence to me.

Here is my code snippet of the main void:

```
private void checkCard(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt, int y, int x){
        if(this.memory.getGrid()[y][x]>0){
            clicks++;
            this.specialIcon(y,x);
            switch (clicks) {
                case 1:
                    pos1[0]=y;
                    pos1[1]=x;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    
                    this.labelCards[pos2[0]][pos2[1]].updateUI();
                    this.grid.updateUI();
                    this.core.updateUI();
                        
                    pos2[0]=y;
                    pos2[1]=x;
                    
                    this.memory.play(pos1, pos2);
                    
                    //CHECK POS1
                    
                    //CHECK POS2        
                    if(!memory.getSolved(pos2)){
                        generateThreadWait();
                    this.labelCards[pos2[0]][pos2[1]].setIcon(new ImageIcon(this.src+"unknown.png"));
                    this.labelCards[pos1[0]][pos1[1]].setIcon(new ImageIcon(this.src+"unknown.png")); 
                    } else if(memory.getSolved(pos2)){
                        this.labelCards[pos2[0]][pos2[1]].setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(this.src+"solved.png"));
                        this.labelCards[pos2[0]][pos2[1]].addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
                            @Override
                            public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                                //DEBUG
                                //System.out.println("DISABLED");
                            }
                        });
                        this.labelCards[pos1[0]][pos1[1]].setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(this.src+"solved.png"));
                        this.labelCards[pos1[0]][pos1[1]].addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
                            @Override
                            public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                                //DEBUG
                                //System.out.println("DISABLED");
                            }
                        });
                    };

                    this.clicks =0; 
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

and the **"generateThreadWait()"** void:

```
private synchronized void generateThreadWait() {
    final java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter dtf = java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
    try {
        System.out.println("Inside synchronized block entry..." + dtf.format(java.time.LocalDateTime.now()));
        this.wait(2000);
        System.out.println("Inside synchronized block exit..." + dtf.format(java.time.LocalDateTime.now()));
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I would be happy for any ideas. Thank you!!!

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) **Don't block the EDT (Event Dispatch Thread).**  The GUI will 'freeze' when that happens.  See [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for details and the fix.

Comment: Don't wait on the EDT ([Event Dispatch Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html)). It is single threaded, any wait on it will halt all UI events. You will have to refactor your code to wait some other way (e.g. using a [Timer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html)).